# Catch GTK accidently multi-enter on entry widget

Tags: python, user-interface, gtk, signals

I'm building a GUI via Python 3 and GTK for Ubuntu. I have set up an entry widget which emits a signal and a callback method, which then will load some data from a database and print those. Now this lookup might take a few seconds. The GUI freezes and that's okay for me, cause the user shouldn't do anything else in the time between.
Now when the user accidentally hits the enter key two or more times, the callback method will be called more than once. Thus, the data get printed too often. 
How can I stop/remove those signals which are queued up while the first signals callback gets executed?

I thought about checking the times and just return in the callback method if the time difference between the method calls is too small. This might actually work, but I want the user to put in new data fats with a barcode scanner. But since I have this problem in an other project I'd like to find a more general solution.

Comment: you could keep text from entry in some variable and in callback you can compare it with new text in entry - if it different then you update data and keep new text from entry in variable.

Comment: Read up on [Gtk.Widget.set_sensitive](http://lazka.github.io/pgi-docs/#Gtk-3.0/classes/Widget.html#Gtk.Widget.set_sensitive) or [GObject.Object.disconnect](http://lazka.github.io/pgi-docs/#GObject-2.0/classes/Object.html#GObject.Object.disconnect)